# Angular Material mat-select dynamic data binding in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, angular-material-6

I am using Angular 6 and Angular Material. When i click on Edit button the Secondary, SSC and Male Value will be initialized on the select. But i can not able to do it. I only able to show Male value on the drop down after clicking Edit button. So i want to show all value on the drop down and pass object for the dynamic selection. Thanks.

My code link here: [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y7ch1a-mmntmk?file=app%2Fselect-value-binding-example.ts)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try with this solution

I have create a demo on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-mat-select-dynamic-data-binding-in-angular?file=app%2Fselect-value-binding-example.html)

> Component.ts

```
  editInfo(educationInfo) {
    this.education_level = educationInfo.aa;
    this.exam_title = educationInfo.bb;
    this.gender = educationInfo.cc;
    this.educationLevelChangeAction(this.education_level);
  }

  educationLevelChangeAction(education) {
    this.exam_title = "";
    let dropDownData = this.educationList.find((data: any) => data.educationLevelName === education);
    if (dropDownData) {
      this.degreeTitleList = dropDownData.degreeTitleList;
    } else {
      this.degreeTitleList = [];
    }

  }
```

> Component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Select Level of Education" name="education_level" (selectionChange)="educationLevelChangeAction(education_level)" [(ngModel)]="education_level" >
    <mat-option *ngFor="let education of educationList" [value]="education.educationLevelName" >{{ education.educationLevelName }}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Select Exam/Degree Title" name="exam_title" [(ngModel)]="exam_title">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let degreeTitle of degreeTitleList" [value]="degreeTitle">{{ degreeTitle }}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="gender">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let gender of genderList" [value]="gender">{{ gender }}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>



<p>You selected: {{education_level}}  {{exam_title}} {{gender}}</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. You have done great work. But there is no value initialization of SSC on Exam/Degree title dropdown after click Edit button. Otherwise it's done perfectly

Comment: can you ssc value show on the Exam/Degree Title dropdown. thanks

Comment: If i put O Level/Other on the Exam/Degree Title drop down rather than SSC then it's not working.It gave only first index but i want only put any value from any index after click Edit button. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174143/discussion-between-monir-tuhin-and-krishna-rathore).

Answer (score 3):

in your code you are binding object to [value] so it can't bind it right, if you change your value to string like you did in gender section will be OK, for e.g:

changing `[value]` from `education` that is object to `education.educationLevelName` that is a string and now it works correctly.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Select Level of Education" name="education_level" (selectionChange)="educationLevelChangeAction(education_level)" [(ngModel)]="education_level" >
    <mat-option *ngFor="let education of educationList" [value]="education.educationLevelName" >{{ education.educationLevelName }}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: thanks @fateme fazli. I have checked your answer. I have tried this before but it's not working appropriately for me.